# Which magnet will last longer?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, time

Say you have a magnet that is used in a brush-less generator. If the brush-less motor was ran (by external force such as water or human interaction) for 400 years, would the magnet that was under use have a weaker magnetic field than a magnet that had not been used at all? In other words, does using a magnet decrease its strength over time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was featured on this month's Safari magazine.  It says:
The electrons of a permanent magnet are aligned in a strict and disciplinary order.  These electrons of a magnetic domain rotate harmoniously in the same direction and that is what is responsible for the magnetic power of a magnet. The magnetic waves travel through the domain walls, passing from one domain to the next and provide strength to the domain structure.  The structure is so tight and coherent that unless the magnet is subjected to extreme temperatures or extreme shock, the disciplinary order of the magnetic domain is not disturbed.  As long as the domain structure remains intact, the magnetic power of a permanent magnet does not diminish.  Under the normal cause of usage, a magnet made of samarium cobalt will lose only about 50% of its magnetic power in 700 years.

I am not sure about what causes it to lose its magnetism.

Comment: Is the magnetic domain rotating harmoniously a product of all of the electrons having the same spin? Also, does this mean that the electrons have to be in the same orbital pattern while having the same spin?

Comment: See [this]( http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM). It explains very simply how electrons have to align their intrinsic magnetic momentum and how magnetic fields of electrons cancel out if the shell is full etc. In short all the factors which determine the magnetism of a permanent magnet.